# Creating GCP cloud function with ingress-settings internal-only doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, external, vpc

Following clear instruction here to https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#create-internal-function with the goal to allow function not to be called by external clients and only by my VMs within VPC.

```
gcloud functions deploy my_func \
  --region us-east4 \
  --timeout 540 \
  --memory 512 \
  --max-instances 20 \
  --runtime python38 \
  --trigger-http \
  --ingress-settings internal-only \
  --allow-unauthenticated
```

Yet, when I test function from one of my VM in the same project and region as my CF I get:

```
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Access is forbidden.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

At this point I am blaming VPC Service Controls (which I have no access to) as a reason for this behavior.

Comment: Is your VM in the same project as the Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with this today. I was able to get it to work by updating the permissions. I granted 'allUsers' the role 'cloud function invoker'